# Dynamic Angular component with template from string

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular-ivy

I have to dynamically (at runtime) create a component with template built of string. This string contains some tags that need to be replaced by Angular components.

For example

HTML template:

```html
<div class="box">
  <div>Lorem ipsum <strong>dolor sit amet</strong></div>
  Event date:
  <span id="datepicker"></span>
  - join us.
</div>
```

needs to be transformed into:

```html
<div class="box">
  <div>Lorem ipsum <strong>dolor sit amet</strong></div>
  Event date:
  <custom-datepicker></custom-datepicker>  <---- here should come Angular component
  - join us.
</div>
```

and rendered.

I tried to do this by using "unofficial" function `ɵcompileComponent` and it works fine -> https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-jtnufx

Unfortunetely it breaks when is built in the `AOT` mode (`ng build --aot -c production`). Getting error:

> Uncaught Error: JIT compiler unavailable

I know that there is an option of disabling aot in `angular.json` but I don't want to do this.

Does anyone know how to handle this?

Comment: Did you try using [innerHTML](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-innerhtml-binding-angular)?

Comment: `innerHTML` just inserts pure HTML code. You cannot compile Angular components